# Darkmode Store in local storage React with Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, themes

How to store the value of the dark mode in localStorage?

can I even do it in this way?

can you guys give me ideas on how?

thank you cheers,

```
function App() {

  const [darkState, setDarkState] = useState("");
  const palletType = darkState ? "dark" : "light";
  const mainPrimaryColor = darkState ? blue[400] : blue[800];
  const mainSecondaryColor = darkState ? grey[800] : grey[100];

  const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: palletType,
      primary: {
        main: mainPrimaryColor,
      },
      secondary: {
        main: mainSecondaryColor,
      },
    },
  });
 function handleThemeChange() {
    setDarkState(!darkState);
  }
 return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
       <IconButton onClick={handleThemeChange()}>
            <Switch checked={darkState} />
        </IconButton>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: localStorage.setItem and getItem didn't work for you? from your question, it seems that you want to update the local storage just as you do setDarkState... what is the issue that you're facing

Comment: well, I tried that but it won't retain the state of the darkState, it stores true or false when toggled but idk what do I store .

Comment: in your conditions, you're not comparing `darkState` to anything... which is why they're not switching

Comment: Sorry if I did not make it clear but basically the toggle works, it toggles into dark to light, my problem was what do I have to store in the local storage so that the preferred (dark or light mode ) is remembered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to do this:

- in useEffect we see if there is something in localStorage and use it
- when we toggle, we keep localStorage updated also

relevant JS:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const existingPreference = localStorage.getItem("darkState");
    if (existingPreference) {
     ( existingPreference === "light")
        ? setDarkState("light")
        : setDarkState("dark");
    } else {
      setDarkState("light");
      localStorage.setItem("darkState", "light");
    }
  }, []);

const handleThemeChange = () => {
    setSwitchState(switchState === true ? false : true);
    if (darkState === "light") {
      setDarkState("dark");
      setMainPrimaryColor(grey[400]);
      setMainSecondaryColor(blue[400]);
      localStorage.setItem("darkState", "dark");
    } else {
      setDarkState("light");
      setMainSecondaryColor(grey[400]);
      setMainPrimaryColor(blue[400]);
      localStorage.setItem("darkState", "light");
    }
  };
```

working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hgepm8)

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how you can set and read from LocalStorage:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTheme(localStorage.getItem("theme"));
  }, []);

  const handleClick = theme => {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
    setTheme(theme);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Selected theme: {theme}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick("light")}>Light</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick("dark")}>Dark</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(true);
const theme = createMuiTheme({
palette: {
  type: darkTheme ? "dark" : "light"
 }
})


useEffect(() => {
  const themeType = localStorage.getItem("dark") || "dark";
  if (themeType != "dark") {
    setDarkTheme(false);
  }
}, []);

const changeTheme = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("dark", darkTheme ? "light" : "dark");
  setDarkTheme(!darkTheme);
};

return (
    <div className="App">
        <p>Selected theme: " {theme} "</p>
        <button onClick={changeTheme}>toggle theme</button>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Hey, please explain what your code actually does to solve the problem so the person asking the question can learn from your solution.